# How do I parametrize a circle that's not centered at the origin?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, geometry, multivariable-calculus, trigonometry

If the circle were centered at the origin, of radius r, then r(cos$\theta$, sin$\theta$) traverses the circle once counterclockwise, for 0 $\le$$\theta$$\le$2$\pi$.

What if the circle were centered at, say, (x,y) = (5,2)?  Also of radius r.

It's not r($cos\theta$ - 5, $sin\theta$-2) ... right?

I'm thinking of the equation for the circle, which would give $(x-5)^2+(y-2)^2=r^2$.

Thanks,

Comment: $(5+r\cos\theta,2+r\sin\theta)$

Comment: You're very close. Think of it like having a circle centered at $(0,0)$ but then you shift everything *uniformly* by $(5,2)$. So it should be $(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta) + (5,2)$.

Comment: ok, got it - thanks so much, @CameronWilliams.

Comment: Your first example circle works with the "angle parameter" and the second one doesn't because $ \ \theta \ $ measures "differences in direction" of rays or vectors emanating from _the origin_.  If you still want to use $ \ \theta \ $ for a circle with the origin not in its interior, the situation is somewhat complicated, since that circle subtends an angle less than $ \ 2 \pi \ $ at the origin and the radius $ \ r \ $ is no longer described by a single function of $ \ \theta \ $ .  It is generally preferred to shift the "center" for a new angle parameter, as **Cameron Williams** describes.

Comment: got it, @RecklessReckoner - thanks for the reminder of why my thinking is incorrect.  (I am particularly weak in plane geometry stuff...)

Answer (score 12):

If the circle $\Gamma$ has equation $(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=R^2$, then
$$x=a+R\cos\alpha,\; y=b+R\sin\alpha$$
parametrize the curve $\Gamma$. Indeed,
$$x=a+R\cos\alpha,\; y=b+R\sin\alpha \Rightarrow 
\cos\alpha=\frac{x-a}{R} ,\; \sin\alpha=\frac{y-b}{R}$$
but,
$$\cos^2\alpha+\sin^2\alpha=1 \Rightarrow \frac{(x-a)^2}{R^2}+\frac{(y-b)^2}{R^2}=1 \Rightarrow (x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=R^2 $$

Comment: You probably mean "$\sin$", not "$sen$". No italics, and different spelling.

Comment: @bubba you can edit the answer accordingly, and if he/she and/or high-cred users accept your edit, it will become part of the answer.